# How to Delete a Role Assignment in Azure using REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-management-api

I am trying to delete a role assignment at the root level in Azure using the REST API. Specifically, I want to remove the Owner role from a user with the email address "mrasheed@gov.pk" I have gathered the object ID of the user and the role definition ID of the Owner role. Now, I'm looking for guidance on how to construct a DELETE request URL.

https://management.azure.com/%7Bscope%7D/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/%7BroleAssignmentName%7D?api-version=2015-07-01

Could someone provide the correct values to replace scope and `roleAssignmentName` in this URL to successfully delete the role assignment?

Additional Information:

The `{scope}` in this case is at the root level, so it should be /.
The `roleAssignmentName` is a GUID that uniquely identifies the role assignment.
The API version is specified as api-version=2015-07-01.
Any guidance on how to construct the DELETE request URL correctly would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to delete a role assignment at the root level in Azure using the REST API. Specifically, I want to remove the Owner role from a user with the email address "mrasheed@gov.pk" I have gathered the object ID of the user and the role definition ID of the Owner role. Now, I'm looking for guidance on how to construct a DELETE request URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman for service principal:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId 
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

I have one user assigned with **Owner** role under subscription scope as below:

[image]

To get the above **role assignment name/ID**, you can run below REST API call:

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subId/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2022-04-01&$filter=principalId eq 'userObjId'
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, run below REST API call to **delete** the role assignment by including **scope** and **role assignment name**:

```http
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subId/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/roleassignment_name?api-version=2022-04-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, role assignment **deleted** successfully as below:

[image]

**Response:**
[Role Assignments - Delete - REST API (Azure Authorization) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-assignments/delete?tabs=HTTP)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me go through it.